# JavaScript - show only CAD price converted from US price

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm retrieving API data that has a price listed in USD. The USD price is being shown on a card in a search listing page.

I want to instead replace the USD price with it's Canadian price. I have a 'formatPrice' function where part of that function converts USD to CAD and it works in a separate area of the web app. Here's the code:

```
export function formatPrice(
  price,
  lang,
  inclCurTxt?: boolean,
  currency?: string,
  receivedCurrency?: string
) {
  let formattedPrice = price;

  let usaRate = 0.74;

  //ENGLISH
  const currencyText = inclCurTxt ? " CAD" : "";
  if (currency != null && currency === "US") {
    //USD
    formattedPrice =
      accounting.formatMoney(Number(price) * usaRate, "$", 0) + currencyText;
  } else {
    //CAD
    formattedPrice = accounting.formatMoney(price, "$", 0) + currencyText;
  }

  // Alter conversions for BFE (English) on single product pages
  if (isEnvironmentBFE()) {
    if (currency !== receivedCurrency) {
      formattedPrice =
        receivedCurrency === "CAD"
          ? accounting.formatMoney(Number(price) * usaRate, "$", 0) +
            currencyText
          : accounting.formatMoney(Number(price) / usaRate, "$", 0) +
            currencyText;
    } else {
      formattedPrice =
        accounting.formatMoney(Number(price), "$", 0) + currencyText;
      // this shows up on ALL prices (cdn or usd) on the listings page, and ONLY
      // on American prices on the single products.
    }
  }

  return formattedPrice;
}
```

I have curPrice which basically uses formatPrice, and it currently shows the USD price on a card in a search listing page. This code works great already - I just want to add onto it. Here's the code:

```
let curPrice =
 this.props.lang === "en"
   ? "Call for price"
   : "Contactez-nous pour le prix";
 if (curProduct.price != null) {
   curPrice = formatPrice(
     curProduct.price.text,
     this.props.lang,
     true
   );
}
```

I've written some code that if current price being pulled into the app from the API is in USD, retrieve the Canadian price from the formatPrice function above and make that appear instead. Here's the code however it's not working:

```
if (curProduct.price?.currency !== "CAD") {
     curPrice = formatPrice(
      curProduct.price.text * 0.74,
      this.props.lang,
      true
    );
 }
```

Comment: i am not sure i fully understand you, 
what the wanted from the code you wrote down to do ?

Comment: @IdoBleicher so from our API, some prices come in stated as a "USD" currency and of course following with a US price point. Our company is based in Canada, so we want to take the USD price coming from the API, convert it to Canadian, and then show that Canadian price instead of the USD price.